# Raster output symbology differs in tool vs. Python

Tags: arcpy, python, raster, symbology

I have a bunch old DOQQs from the 90's that are projected in NAD27, giving them the black angled collar you see in the image. I am trying to set the collar to null by running SetNull on Value = 0. If I run the Set Null tool from the SA toolbox it turns out perfectly. If I run SetNull in the python window however, it changes the symbology from stretched to unique values, requiring me to manually change it back on every DOQQ. Is there a way to keep the symbology set to stretched in the save output, or to change it back in Python?

```
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.workspace = r'F:\DOQQ1991\Tiles'
rastiles = arcpy.ListRasters()
for tile in rastiles:
    nullras = SetNull(tile, tile, "VALUE = 0")
    nullras.save("{0}\{1}".format(r'F:\DOQQ1991\NullTiles', tile))
```

[image: Results]

Comment: From memory DOQQ are an integer data type which is why the change to classified.. try Set Raster Properties https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000015z000000 to enforce nodata = 0 instead of SetNull, you can also reinforce the data_type = 'GENERIC' just to be sure. Note this tool works on the input image and doesn't create a new one so will be much faster, please ensure you have a backup of your originals before proceeding just in case the Set Raster Properties ruins the raster.

Comment: You were right about the integer type. Converting the SetNull output to float will force it to revert back to a stretched symbology (and will even retain it after converting back to Int). So thank you for that workaround. The properties tool isn't effective in this case as I need the values to actually change to NoData. Still wondering why they would make it so running it through python causes the symbology change when the tool does not. I suppose I could just script it as arcpy.gp.SetNull_sa, but I feel like there should be another way to preserve the stretched setting.

Comment: Luke, if you found the solution to your question (as pointed ou by Michael) you can add your own answer. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer. Tks.